# GAS script change date and time in sheet after merge

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column with dates in a couple sheets, and when I merge data from this sheets to another spreadsheet for some reason it adds 10 hours to each date.

```js
function runTransferToMasterSheet() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID");
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file; 
  var data;
  
  var sheetMaster = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('sheetURL').getSheets()[0];
  
  var range = sheetMaster.getRange("A2:G120000");
  range.clear();
  while(contents.hasNext()){
    file = contents.next();    
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheets()[0];
    
    // delete row with columns names
    sheet.deleteRow(1);

    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    
    setDataToMaster(sheetMaster, sheet, data);
  }
  
}

function setDataToMaster(sheetMaster, sheet, data) {
  var sheetMaster = sheetMaster; 
  var sheet = sheet;
  var startRow = 1; 
  var data = data;
  
  if (sheetMaster.getDataRange().getValue() == null) {
    sheetMaster.getRange(2, 1, data.length, 7).setValues(data);
  } else {
    sheetMaster.getRange((sheetMaster.getLastRow() + 1), 1, data.length, 7).setValues(data);
  }
}
```

Date in one of sheets that will be merged
6/13/2018 11:10:00

Date in final sheet
6/13/2018 21:10:00

Comment: Consider adding logging to `setDataToMaster`, I'm guessing this could have something to do with timezones, try logging `data` and see if those values are correct, you may need to set a timezone to those dates before you can add them to the new sheet. This is a bit of a guess, could you give us a small dataset of your sheet so we can see if we can replicate the issue?

Comment: Add a simple example of the date format

Answer (score 1):

For some reason sheets that I merge(I got them using some api) has the wrong time zone, so the decision was before merging use:

```js
mySpreadSheet.setSpreadsheetTimeZone(Session.getScriptTimeZone());
```